# List of users from Active Directory to Excel file

Tags: python, active-directory

I'm relatively new to Python, but I'm trying to get a list of all my active users from Active Directory and export to an Excel file. I would prefer this done in Python since that's the language I'm most familiar with.

Most of the code I've seen uses an ldap3 module. However, it doesn't some to be fully accessible in vscode or maybe I did something wrong. Can you help me figure out how to do this?

Comment: please tell us what you have tried so far and share some code

Comment: Now I'm getting an unsupported hash type MD4 error. Here's the first part of the code I used. I'll post the second part next.

import sys
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, ALL_ATTRIBUTES,ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES, AUTO_BIND_NO_TLS, SUBTREE
from ldap3.core.exceptions import LDAPCursorAttributeError

server_name = 'server name'
domain_name = 'domain name'
user_name = 'user name'
password = 'password'

format_string = '{:25} {:>6} {:19} {:19} {}'
print(format_string.format('User', 'Logins', 'Last Login', 'Expires', 'Description'))

Comment: Part 2:

server = Server(server_name, get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, user='{}\\{}'.format(domain_name, user_name), password=password, authentication=NTLM, auto_bind=True)
conn.search('dc={},dc=local'.format(domain_name), '(objectclass=person)', attributes=[ALL_ATTRIBUTES, ALL_OPERATIONAL_ATTRIBUTES])
for e in conn.entries:
    try:
        desc = e.description
    except LDAPCursorAttributeError:
        desc = ""

print(format_string.format(str(e.name), str(e.logonCount), str(e.lastLogon) [:19], str(e.accountExpires) [:19], desc))